# How to use an external image as pattern in svg-edit?

Tags: svg-edit

I'm a new to **svg-edit**, and I have a problem with using external link as pattern image.

Svg-edit delete the part

```
xlink:href="http://www.micromark.com/RS/SR/Product/85373_T.jpg"
```

when I apply modifications in the source :

```
<svg width="640" height="480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:undefined="http:/www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <pattern x="0" y="0" width="100" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="testGilles" height="100" xmlns:xlink="http:/www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
            <image id="svg_3" width="100" height="100" xlink:href="http://www.micromark.com/RS/SR/Product/85373_T.jpg"/>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <g>
        <title>Layer 1</title>
        <rect id="svg_1" height="225" width="238" y="87" x="82" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="url(#testGilles)"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Does anyone knows why ?

I hope this is clear, it's not easy for me to explain it in English :)

Comment: Ok, I found it ...
A "/" was missing in first line, in xmlns:undefined="http:/www.w3.org/1999/xlink"